# Can't set values in an std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<class>>

Tags: c++, class, c++11, shared, stdmap

I'm trying to make a map as showed in the title of this post to link certain bass classes to MQTT topic titles.

I've got I working with raw (c style) pointers, but as I've learned in school smart pointers would be a better design option.

The problem doesn't occur when instantiating the map, but when I want to assign data to it.

The way I've got it working perfectly is:

```
std::map<std::string,sensors*> factory;
factory["sensorTwo"]= new sensor1;
```

In this code "sensors" is the baseclass of sensor1;

When I try to do it like this:

```
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<sensors>> factory;
factory["sensorOne"]= std::make_shared<sensors> (sensor1);
```

The compiler asks for a primary expression before ';' on the second line.
The assignment in the first example obviously doesn't work with the shared_ptr, but does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

main looks as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

#include "sensors.h"
#include "sensor1.h"
#include "sensor2.h"


int main()
{
    //std::map<std::string,sensors*> factory;

    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<sensors>> factory;
    factory["sensorOne"]= std::make_shared<sensor1> ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a3e115f04392bc2).  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Seeing your `main` doesn't help much if we don't know what's in your three `*.h` files.

Comment: MQTT is unexplained.  Either useless (so should be deleted), or needs explanation.

Comment: Christian, those files are almost empty, just empty classes where the numbered ones are derived classes from sensors.

Yakk, it's not important for the solution, just a small background on why I want it this way.

Comment: @Xinq: If they are almost empty, then it should have been even easier to create an MCVE without them, probably by moving the definition of the `sensors` class and the `#include <map>` directly into `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you have declared structures `Foo` and `Bar` as follows:

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};
```

Correct syntax for [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) to make a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` pointing to a `Bar` instance is:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sp = std::make_shared<Bar>();
```

From your first example, `Foo` is `sensors` and `Bar` is `sensor1`. So your code should not be:

```
factory["sensorOne"]= std::make_shared<sensors> (sensor1);
```

But:

```
factory["sensorOne"]= std::make_shared<sensor1> ();
```

Comment: Do you maybe also know how to delete the object from memory? (single and if possible also dynamically in a loop)

Comment: Since you're using smart pointers, you don't have to manage deletion: memory will be released when the last `share_ptr` pointing to it will be destroyed

Comment: ah yeah I see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an include to `<map>`, it can cause this error message.

Comment: @einpoklum Actually, this looks like a possibility that explains the error.  The OP's example isn't a [MCVE], so everyone is basically guessing.

Comment: @Yakk Then wouldn't the error be for the first line and not the second?

Comment: I indeed forgot to include that in the post but I do have it included in the main.cpp

Comment: @Xinq: That's why MCVEs are required. Never post code which you have not tested before.

Comment: @Yakk: You're right that it's just a guess, I'm essentially suggestion to didiz to make these kinds of guesses as a comment. By the way - thank you to the downvote for undoing your downvote :-)